# compound comparisons in bash

Tags: bash, comparison, conditional-operator

can anybody explain why the following bash code involving compound operators is not behaving as expected?  basically, nothing enters the if statement inside the for loop but i am passing it correct parameters that should return something by running:
./my_bash_script 20100101 20120101

dates.txt is a list of all days since 2000

```
#!/bin/bash

old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
lines=($(cat dates.txt)) # array
IFS=$old_IFS

for (( i=1; i<${#lines[@]}; i++ ))
do
  if [[ ${line[$i]} -ge $1 && ${line[$i]} -le $2 ]]; then
      echo 0 > ${line[$i]} # redirect to file
      echo ${line[$i]}
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared an array named `lines`, but then you try to access it as though it were named `line`. You need to change every occurrence of `${line[$i]}` to `${lines[$i]}`.

Better yet, you can dispense with the arithmetic for-loop, and write:

```
for line in "${lines[@]}" ; do
```

which will let you refer to the line as `$line` or `"$line"` rather than as `${lines[$i]}`.

(By the way, how come you have that logic to modify `$IFS`? It seems like its default value would work just as well.)

Comment: I fixed the bug of line --> lines and now the code works, turns out that typo was the problem, thanks.

Comment: @user788171: You're welcome! But I still think you should use a regular `for`-loop.